# how i can access the variable value outside the map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, push

i want to access the variable outside the map with value but the value outside the map in null
here is my code

```
let currentUser = await User.findById(req.user._id);
  let wordDetails = [];
  let findSameWord;
  let wordDetail = [];

  currentUser.learn.map(
    catchAsync(async (words) => {
       let wordDetail = await Learn.findById(words);
       wordDetails.push(wordDetail);  
       console.log(wordDetails); //here get me correct array
       return wordDetails;
     
    })
  );

  console.log(wordDetails); // here is an empty array
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `.map()` when you're not interested in its return value.

Comment: I think if you remove the ``return``, you will get the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with that:

```js
let currentUser = await User.findById(req.user._id);
let wordDetails = [];
let findSameWord;
let wordDetail = [];

await Promise.all(currentUser.learn.map(
    catchAsync(async (words) => {
        let wordDetail = await Learn.findById(words);
        wordDetails.push(wordDetail);
        console.log(wordDetails); //here get me correct array
        return wordDetails;

    })
));

console.log(wordDetails); // here is an empty array
```

Comment: i do like this but unfortunately didn't work as i expected